# Comparison on $\Bbb R^2$ between Euclidean topology and lexicographic topology

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to study the relationship between the Euclidean topology and the lexicographic order topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

My claim is that the lexicographic order topology $\sigma$ is finer than the Euclidean one $\tau$, that is $\tau \subset \sigma$.

To prove that, I need to show:

1. That every open Euclidean open set is open in the lexicographic order topology.
2. There exists at least an open subset for $\sigma$ but not for $\tau$.
3. Let B an open set for the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$, for example the open ball centered at $P$ with radius $R$. For every $x \in \Bbb R$, let
   $$
   B_{x}= B \; \cap \; \left ( \left \{ x \right \} \times \Bbb R \right )
   $$
   $B_x=\left \{ x \right \} \times (a,b)=((x,a),(x,b))$ and this interval is open for $\sigma$.
4. Sets of the type $(0,y)$ with $0<y<1$ are open for the lexicographic order topology $\sigma$ but not for $\tau$.

Does it work?

Comment: 3 needs a bit more work. You can also use the open squares as a base, which is easier. 3 (if bettered) and 4 together would do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, why do I have to use a base?

Comment: You use a base too, of open balls. I propose to use another.

Answer (score 0):

The lexicographic order on $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R_d \times \Bbb R_e$, where $\Bbb R_d$ is the discrete topology on the reals, and $\Bbb R_e$ the Euclidean (usual) topology on the reals.

As $\Bbb R^2_e \simeq \Bbb R_e \times \Bbb R_e$ the proper inclusion is immediate from the proper inclusion of topologies in $\mathcal{T}_{\Bbb R_e} \subsetneq \mathcal{T}_{\Bbb R_d}$

Comment: I need to show that without using homeomorphisms.